# How to stream a `Seq[Future[_]]` into either a `Future[Stream[_]]` or a `Stream[_]` such that it can consumed as it becomes available in order?

Tags: scala, concurrency, future

As a first attempt, I tried to use `Await.result` on the head of the `Seq` and then use the lazy `#::` `Stream` constructor. However, it seems to not work as good as expected since I haven't found a way to tell the scheduler to prioritize the order of the list nor does the compiler recognize it as `@tailrec`.

```scala
  implicit class SeqOfFuture[X](seq: Seq[Future[X]]) {
    lazy val stream: Stream[X] =
      if (seq.nonEmpty) Await.result(seq.head) #:: seq.tail.stream
      else Stream.empty
  }
```

I am attempting this since `Future.collect` seems to wait until the whole *strict* `Seq` is available/ready in order to map/flatmap/transform it further. (And there are other computations I might start with the stream of intermedieate results)

(Proto)Example of usage:

```
val searches = [SearchParam1, SearchParam2..., SearchParam200]
// big queries that take a some 100ms each for ~20s total wait
val futureDbResult = searches.map(search => (quill)ctx.run { query(search) }).stream
// Stuff that should happen as results become available instead of blocking/waiting ~20 seconds before starting
val processedResults = futureDbResult.map(transform).filter(reduce)

// Log?
processedResults.map(result => log.info/log.trace)
//return lazy processedResults list or Future {processedResults}
???
```

Comment: I doubt this can be safely done. For this kind of use case, I would recommend a robust **Streaming** library like: `fs2`, `monix` _(**Observable**)_ or `akka-streams`.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I will check them out.

Comment: Just realized that the best approach would be to map computations into each individual Future and collect as late as possible. (To reduce or return a single future)

Oh well, this is food for thought regardless

Comment: `Future.sequence(futureOfSequence).map(_.toStream)` will give you a `Future[Stream[_]]`

Comment: You should avoid this `Await.result(seq.head)` approach as Await is blocking and doing this is no different from a sequential blocking get (which you certainly don't want).  And if you are looking for a truly non-blocking approach then you first require a pipeline which supports both pull and push functionality. It just can not be done with simpler constructs like Stream etc. As Luis pointed out, you need to look into something like fs2, monix or akka-streams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have pointed out, you really should look into a real streaming library like `fs2` or `monix`. I personally think monix is a good fit if you're interfacing with `Future` and only need it in a small part of your application. It has great APIs and documentation for this use-case.

Here's a small demo for your use-case:

```
import monix.eval.Task
import monix.execution.Scheduler.Implicits.global
import monix.reactive.Observable

import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.util.Random

// requires: libraryDependencies += "io.monix" %% "monix" % "3.0.0"
object Main {

  val searchParams = (1 to 200).map(n => s"Search $n")

  /**
    * Simulates a query. If your library returns a Future, you can wrap it with `Task.deferFuture`
    */
  def search(param: String): Task[String] =
    Task(s"Result for $param").delayResult(Random.between(25, 250).milliseconds)

  val results: Task[List[String]] =
    Observable
      .fromIterable(searchParams)
      .mapParallelUnordered(parallelism = 4)(param => search(param))
      .mapEval { result =>
        Task(println(result)).map(_ => result) // print intermediate results as feedback
      }
      .toListL // collect results into List

  /**
    * If you aren't going all-in on monix, you probably run the stream into a Future with `results.runToFuture`
    */
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = results.map(_ => ()).runSyncUnsafe()
}
```

You can think of `Task` as a lazy and more powerful `Future`. `Observable` is a (reactive) stream which will automatically back-pressure if downstream is slow. In this example only 4 queries will run in parallel and the other will wait until a "slot" becomes available to run.
Keep in mind that in those libraries side-effects (like `println` have to be wrapped in `Task` (or `IO` depending on what you use).

You can run this example locally if you provide the monix-dependency and play around with it to get a feel for how it works.